# Getting error while inputting value at 2d vector

Tags: c++

I am using Codeblock to write c++ code.  I was trying to input value at 2d vector. But it is getting an error. I am new at c++ and I have already searched at google but haven't found any solution. This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <vector<double>> customar_data;
    double value;
    cin >> value;
    customar_data[0][0].push_back(value);
    cout >> customar_data[0][0];

    return 0;
}
```

This is what codeblocks compiler showing

[image]

Comment: You never specified a size for your outer vector, thus you're accessing it out of bounds here: `ustomar_data[0]`. And even if you would have specified a size your statement should be `customar_data[0].push_back(value);`.

Comment: You probably should have a read about [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).

Comment: But how can I input data at 2d vector? Suppose I want to add value at `customar_data[0][0]`.

Comment: And I hear that don't need to specify vector size. It automatically takes size.

Comment: How many elements should be stored in the 1st dimension? Just size your first dimension first, then input the data for it.

Comment: _"And I hear that don't need to specify vector size. It automatically takes size."_ It does at the first dimension level using `push_back`, but only at one dimension level at a time.

Answer (score 0):

For the compiler's error, look at the types of the expressions involved.

- `customar_data` is a `vector <vector <double>>`
- `customar_data[0]` is a `<vector <double>>`
- `customar_data[0][0]` is a `double`

The compiler complains when you request a member function (`push_back`) of the non-class type `double`.

---

For the logical error, look at what you are requesting. You start by [constructing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) an empty `vector` (of `vector<double>`). Then you try to [access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) the first element of this empty vector. You can avoid the need to specify the vector's size during construction, or you can access elements without adding them to the constructed vector, but you cannot do both. Vectors do not automatically increase in size as a result of accessing elements that had not existed.

The valid indices/subscripts to access are the non-negative integers less than the vector's `size()`. A default constructed vector starts with a size of zero, so there are no valid indices (you would need a non-negative integer less than zero). If you know how big you want the outermost vector to be when you construct it, you may want to specify that.

```
vector <vector<double>> customar_data(10);
// At this point, customar_data[0] through customar_data[9] can be used.
// Each of these elements is an empty vector of doubles.
```

If you do not know how big the outermost vector is going to be, you'll need to add each element *before* you use it. (This is intentionally singular; you can add an element, use it, then add another.)

```
vector <vector<double>> customar_data;
customar_data.push_back(vector<double>()); // Adds an empty vector as the first element.
customar_data[0].push_back(20.0); // Adds a value to the vector that is the first element.
// At this point, customar_data[0][0] is valid and has the value 20.0.
```

You might find that the `emplace_back` member function is more convenient than `push_back`, but let's go one step at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much JaMiT... It's really helpfull.